# Blank Swf after printing from another app

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

Ok, so i am having a problem, where i developed an app that uses the webcam, adds an image and then takes a picture, well, i implemented textbook style the printjob, and well everytime after printing my swf goes blank.

[As3 printing problem, blanks swf after print or cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021557/as3-printing-problem-blanks-swf-after-print-or-cancel)

But now i have been continuing testing, and i found out, that if i print from another application and then comeback, my video stream from the webcam is blank, this has no sense at all, since i am printing from another app.

Please i need help with this, i have found one additional case:

http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=781089

What is going on here i mean, this must be a flash player issue right.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on another computer?

Comment: Yes i have tested it on my Development Computer (Os X 10.5.8) and on deployment Machine: Windows XP... Actually i tested in three computers since this app is meant to be deployed on kiosk advertising, if you are interested you can check the source code and take a peek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your question but have you tried setting up a crossdomain policy file so you can get access the BitmapData of the image you're trying to print?